# pybrain datasets insert tuple

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, pybrain

I use pybrain datasets and I want to add a list (or a tuple) of tuples as the input value of the items in the dataset. For example:

```
from pybrain.datasets import ClassificationDataSet
ds = ClassificationDataSet(2, 1, nb_classes=2)
ds.addSample([(2,3),(4,5)], [0]) # or ds.addSample(((2,3),(4,5)), [0])
```

or

```
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
ds = SupervisedDataSet(2, 1)
ds.appendLinked([(2,3),(4,5)], [0])
```

but apparently I can give only integers or float numbers as input. Could you please help me?